# "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." error when importing tensorflow with rocm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm interested in learning tensorflow with pycharm for a few projects with an amd system (r5 3600x, rx 5700xt). After realizing I was only going to get this to work with my gpu if I installed linux, I installed ubuntu 18.04 to dualboot with Windows 10, since it looked like the most supported for rocm. I followed the tutorial here, except I didn't make the virtual environment.
https://www.videogames.ai/Install-ROCM-Machine-Learning-AMD-GPU
When typing in `sudo apt install rocm-libs miopen-hip cxlactivitylogger` it said it couldn't find the package cxlactivitylogger, in the comments the author said he would look into it but it wasnt necessary to install tensorflow, so I ignored it. I then opened up pycharm, the tensorflow package wouldn't detect so I installed tensorflow-rocm again in pycharm just to make sure, but it gives me this error whenever I try to import it in pycharm or in the terminal.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: librccl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/waiai/PycharmProjects/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: librccl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I'm fairy inexperienced with linux, so all of this has just given me a headache, I've tried installing pytorch before this, but I was getting similar errors so I decided to try tensorflow. If anyone can bother to hold my hand through this it would be greatly appretiated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed, I installed rccl with

```
sudo apt install rccl
```